# Intuitive way of presenting options on toggle-able items

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, simplicity

This question is a little hard to explain so I'll do my best to explain. I'm creating an alarm type app where a user chooses a location and has two options they can decide if they want on or not. Each of these options has a set of sub-options they will also need to choose if they want the main option to be on.

e.g. Sound can either be on or off and has these sub options

- Song or Tone (i.e. song or ringtone) (Choose one)
- Volume

I'm having trouble deciding how to present these options and sub options as intuitively as possible. Normally on a web application I would have these in a form like fashion and have pop-up windows or drop-down menus for each sub-option but unfortunately this is a mobile app so neither of those would work in this situation. My questions are:

- How can I present a simple and intuitive way for the user to toggle these options and have the sub-options be present?
- Should I bring the user to a different screen or slide up screen (iPhone) for each sub-option or some how incorporate them all into the same screen?

Answer (score 1):

Intuitive often means well known and usual.

It seems like in your case you can place all the suboptions on a single screen and use a dedicated screen for choosing a song from a library with help of a standard settings UI controls and behavior:

[image: alarm settings]